# Trigger click on all elements with class

Tags: jquery

Here's the situation...

I have multiple buttons with a class `.delete-rule`

I have a click event tied to that class:

```
$('.delete-rule').click(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

**The Problem:** When I `trigger` a click event on that class, the only event that fires is the click event on the first button - none of the subsequent buttons' click events fire.

How do I get all buttons with the `.delete-rule` class to fire when I call:

`$('.delete-rule').trigger('click')`?

Comment: Are you adding subsequent `.delete-rule` elements dynamically? [Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/1dzrt8qu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to work for dynamically added elements.**

There are a few ways you could do this: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xh7qzca1/2/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-rule', function(){
    $('.delete-rule').animate({'left': '200px'}, 200);
});
```

or

```
$('.delete-rule').click(function(){
    $('.delete-rule').each(function() {
        //Do Stuff
    });
});
```

or

```
var deleteRule = function(){
    //Do Stuff
};

$('.delete-rule').click(deleteRule);

$('.delete-rule').trigger('click');
```

Are you adding content dynamically? Any additional information of what you are trying to do would be very helpful. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, sorry. These buttons with the `.delete-rule` class are getting added dynamically.

Comment: Updated the answer to match dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why an `each` function is necessary. As you see here, simply concatenating a `click` trigger works just fine.

Default background color is blue, but the click event swaps it to red. as you can see, all elements are red, and not only the first one.

http://jsfiddle.net/748z0yn6/

```
$('.delete-rule').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"background-color": "red"});
}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You example should work unless you´re updating the DOM with new elements or using nested elements together with [stopProgation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

See my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7uh5doj/) where I´m binding the click event handler using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to enable DOM manipulation.

```
$('body').append('<button class="delete-rule">D</button>');

$(document).on('click', '.delete-rule', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.type, $(this).val(), 'Do stuff');
});


setTimeout(function() {
    $('.delete-rule').click(); // tigger('click')
}, 3000);
```